# How to disable Travis CI pipeline for draft or WIP pull requests on GitHub?

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-api

I would like to avoid overwhelming the build. Has anybody done it before?

Answer (score -1):

There is a feature called conditional builds. You can match against function results, regexes, attributes in lists .. and so on.

See here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs
and here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditions-v1

Comment: None of those conditions include drafts...

Comment: You could just filter for `WIP` in the PR name. But for drafts, there is no support as it seems: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-conditions/issues/27